# Treat only part of a textbox as a hyperlink on Active Reports

Tags: hyperlink, activereports

I have the need to generate a report using ActiveReports with links inserted on the text. There may be more than one link on the text, they could be anywhere, and only a specific part of the full text needs to be marked as a link. Is there a way to do this?
E.G.:

Visit my [homepage](http://www.fakeuri.forsample.com/pages.aspx?fakeparam=1) or the company's [web site](http://www.fakeuri.forsample.com/pages.aspx?fakeparam=web_site)!

I've tried with the Rich Text Control but it does not show links even if I load an html page. And the Hyperlink property of textboxes is no good because they only handle one single hyperlink and cannot mark where on the text is that link.

Any ideas will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now the support for hyperlinks in Richtextbox is not supported in AR7. However, the feature might get added in added.

Regards,
Mohita